# Trying to build a fresh Xcode project, but they keep failing because " Line 14: EntityRef: expecting ';' "

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

For starters, I'm completely new to coding. I'm trying to learn Swift through youtube tutorials but  when they tell me to build i always get Build Failed, because Line 14: EntityRef: expecting ';'

I've tried this in fresh Xcode projects that are still unscathed, yet i always get this error and its holding me back quite a lot. When i click 'LaunchScreen.xib' i get the same error.

Thanks in advance for any help that may solve my problem.

P.S this is the newest Xcode 6 beta.

Comment: post relevant code where you get the error

Comment: I have no idea where the relevant code is. It doesn't say.

Comment: Xcode standard procedure for strange errors: Delete "Derived Data" folder. Restart. If that doesn't help reinstall Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is rename your project without "!,@£$%^&*" or something like that

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was removing the "&" character from the Organization Name.

1. Select the Project in the Project Navigator
2. On the right hand side pane (the File Inspector), under Project Document remove any special characters from the Organization Name.

I guess the character was not escaped right in the Launch Screen template.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of me, an invalid character was included in a value of text in the label tag in the "LaunchScreen.xib" file.
Probably the user name that started xcode

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "LaunchScreen.xib" from your project and you are good to go.